# organizing data that I am pulling and saving to CSV

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, export-to-csv

The Link below has a lot of layers to it's business listings. I am trying to pull all the contact info for each company. I have code that I used in the past for tables that I scraped in the past but it's a total mess and not pulling any results. Please help

https://www.estatesales.net/companies/NJ/Northern-New-Jersey

````
import pandas as pd
import csv
url_list=['https://www.estatesales.net/companies/NJ/Northern-New-Jersey']
with open('file.csv','w') as csvfile

    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    #Write the headers
    writer.writerow(['Name','City','State','Telephone'])
        #convert second column of 1st dataframe to a list and write to csv file
        writer.writerow(list(dfs[0][1])[:-1])
```
````

Comment: What is `dfs` in your code? You're never actually fetching the url in order to get its contents, it seems like there are some parts of your code missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas to do that. Collect all the data into a dataframe, then just write the dataframe to file.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4

root_url = 'https://www.estatesales.net'
url_list=['https://www.estatesales.net/companies/NJ/Northern-New-Jersey']

results = pd.DataFrame()
for url in url_list:
    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    companies = soup.find_all('app-company-city-view-row')
    for company in companies:
        try:
            link = root_url + company.find('a',{'itemprop':"name url"})['href']
            print(link)
        except:
            continue
        response = requests.get(link)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        company_info = soup.find('div', {'id':'CompanyInfo'})
        try:
            name = company_info.find('h1',{'itemprop':"name"}).text
        except:
            name = 'N/A'
        try:
            city = company_info.find('span',{'itemprop':"addressLocality"}).text
        except:
            city = 'N/A'
        try:
            state = company_info.find('span',{'itemprop':"addressRegion"}).text
        except:
            state = 'N/A'
        try:
            phone = company_info.find('span',{'itemprop':"telephone"}).text
        except:
            phone = 'N/A'

        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[name, city, state, phone]], columns = ['Name','City','State','Telephone'])
        results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)

results.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
                                                  Name       ...             Telephone
0                               Hub Estate Liquidation       ...        (862) 259-5364
1                Pink Dog Estate And Moving Sales, LLC       ...        (201) 674-7464
2         Remember When Antiques And Estate Sales, LLC       ...        (917) 410-7100
3                                     Always Nostalgia       ...        (201) 388-2598
4                                  Before & After Corp       ...        (201) 747-5342
5                               Discovery Estate Sales       ...        (908) 620-1776
6               Plum Cottage Estate Sales & Appraisals       ...        (732) 788-4101
7                              Decorate On A Dime, LLC       ...        (908) 380-3340
8    Remmey Antiques & Fine Art Appraisers & Auctio...       ...        (973) 425-1608
9                            Easy Picking Estate Sales       ...        (917) 691-6132
10                               EstateSalesByOlga.com       ...        (908) 337-4240
11                                          Real McCoy       ...        (973) 418-1286
12                           Then And Now Estate Sales       ...        (201) 259-8408
13                                       Insideout,llc       ...        (215) 630-4942
14           Beacon Hill Estate Sales & Appraisals LLC       ...        (908) 601-5381
15                            Lori Palmer Estate Sales       ...        (732) 809-3382
16              Somerset Appraisal And Estate Services       ...        (908) 872-6236
17           Central Jersey Estate Sales & Liquidators       ...        (908) 625-1622
18                       C. T. Peters Inc., Appraisers       ...        (732) 747-9450
19                 Treasures Of Yesterday Estate Sales       ...        (201) 446-2790
20                Caring Transitions Of Central Jersey       ...        (732) 307-3881
21                  Attic To The Basement Estate Sales       ...        (732) 778-7674
22                                Griffin Estate Sales       ...        (908) 447-3044
23                              Dodge Estate Sales LLC       ...        (973) 714-1401
24                               Estate Sales By Kathy       ...        (732) 674-7330
25                                     Curated Estates       ...        (917) 470-9255
26                              Brownstone Liquidators       ...        (845) 821-3254
27                                 Jersey Estate Sales       ...        (973) 428-1906
28                                  Arkay Resale, Inc.       ...        (201) 741-4165
29                                    Vinylpiggy's LLC       ...        (551) 804-7152
..                                                 ...       ...                   ...
116                  Classic Estate Sales & Appraisals       ...        (201) 370-4021
117                                       Sullivintage       ...        (732) 890-3485
118                                    A Trotters Sale       ...        (973) 819-8685
119                                 Shore Estate Sales       ...        (732) 616-3371
120                                   Liberty Antiques       ...        (908) 581-6987
121                               Johnson Estate Sales       ...        (201) 259-0442
122                               Buy-Gone Trading Co.       ...        (201) 665-8208
123                      Elite Auctions & Estate Sales       ...        (732) 751-1112
124                                  The Butler Did It       ...        (908) 892-8133
125                       Drama Mama Home Estate Sales       ...        (862) 400-2081
126                          New Jersey Gold Resources       ...                   N/A
127                                          Lyrix Inc       ...        (973) 632-1600
128                           Home Ready Services, LLC       ...        (908) 370-3062
129                      Bygone Days Estate Sales, LLC       ...        (973) 857-9069
130                                 Fourty Fifty Sixty       ...        (973) 341-7891
131                                       True Salvage       ...        (973) 970-5400
132                      Ina's Antiques & Estate Sales       ...        (908) 578-4118
133                    Caring Transitions Jersey Shore       ...        (732) 681-0054
134                          ENCORE ESTATE & TAG SALES       ...        (973) 220-4611
135                                           Ajtrains       ...        (732) 859-1606
136                   M.T. House Estate & Moving Sales       ...        (973) 865-1173
137                                       WCL Antiques       ...        (201) 739-3173
138                                      Kens Antiques       ...        (732) 306-2717
139                                 Lee Dowdy Antiques       ...        (201) 650-7208
140                              Garage Sale Goddesses       ...        (201) 612-8510
141                                 M & J Estate Sales       ...        (908) 956-4284
142                                     Granny's Attic       ...        (201) 632-0102
143                              Red Barn Estate sales       ...        (201) 481-5428
144                             D&r Estate & Tag Sales       ...        (201) 573-1009
145                           Always Remember When LLC       ...        (347) 244-1591

[146 rows x 4 columns]
```